# View details of a certificate in Android

Tags: java, android, security, certificate

How to display details of the subject in a certificate (DER format ie .cer file) in java ? eg: email, country, Name or seperate OIDs etc.

Reading a certificate could be done from the above code. Will work in Android as well. Thank you GreyBeardedGeek. But to more elaborate on it (As curious requested), if you display the subject details by using methods getSubjectDN() or cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getname() it will display the whole details. Some may be encoded. I believe it ASN1.(not sure). What I need is to extract only the information I need. For an example please refer the output of the code for a sample certificate I had created. using method - cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getname() Subject Name 2.5.4.5=#130d4e2d61626c652f49542f303130,2.5.4.72=#1308456e67696e656572,2.5.4.41=#13104e7577616e20446520416c6d65696461,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16106e7577616e406e2d61626c652e62697a,OU=Information Technology,O=N-able Pvt Ltd\ ,ST=Western,C=LK

2.5.4.5 is an OID (Object Identifier) which is encoded.

Using method - getSubjectDN()

OID.2.5.4.5=N-able/IT/010, OID.2.5.4.72=Engineer, OID.2.5.4.41=Nuwan De Almeida, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16106E7577616E406E2D61626C652E62697A, OU=Information Technology, O="N-able Pvt Ltd ", ST=Western, C=LK

Here also some information is encoded eg: email address.

So coming back to my question , how can we extract information(not encoded) separately based on the OID. Further if you install the certificate in windows OS you could view the subject information correctly.What I need is a code to get the OID value information passing the OID in java, to extract subject details separately.

Thank you again in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Bouncy Castle ASN.1 parsing libraries and especially `X500Name`. It can parse a distinguished name (DN) into its parts (CN, O, etc.).

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Nikolay.  I am trying this in Android. This is for My research. However even though I include Bouncy-castle or Spongy-castle JAR files in the project , X509Name is getting depreciated. Also there's noway to obtain a X509Name from a X509Certificate file. Thank you very much. If some one has any ideas it is very much helpful.

Comment: `X500Name` (not 509) certainly is not deprecated and it has a constructor that takes a `String`. Exploring the source for examples also helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (no error handling included) will produce an instance of X509Certificate from the .cer file. You can then use that object's methods to inspect the properties of the certificate. The code is generic java, but should work in Android.

```
X509Certificate cert = null;

FileInputStream fis = null;
ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;

String source = "certificate.cer";
String certType = "X.509"

fis = new FileInputStream(source);
byte[] value = new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(value);

bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(value);

java.security.cert.CertificateFactory cf = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance(certType);
cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bais);
```